# Using repository in Mongobee migration

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, jhipster

I'm using the latest version of jhipster up to now ( 3.6.1 ) and it's using MongoBee for mongodb migration. I want to know about the consequences of using spring data repository or MongoTemplate in MongoBee migration class

I don't want to use DB class because I have to write my property name as string like below. So I want to use my Entity ( Document ) and using setter for that.

```
@ChangeSet(order = "01", author = "initiator", id = "01-addAuthorities")
public void addAuthorities(DB db) {
    DBCollection authorityCollection = db.getCollection("jhi_authority");
    authorityCollection.insert(
        BasicDBObjectBuilder.start()
            .add("_id", "ROLE_ADMIN")
            .get());
    authorityCollection.insert(
        BasicDBObjectBuilder.start()
            .add("_id", "ROLE_USER")
            .get());
}
```

So another question is if I use Entity for saving in db, what happens if I change property name in Entity after the changeset applied?

@juliendubois I asked this question in your twitter and you told me to write in StackOverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the MongoBee documentation](https://github.com/mongobee/mongobee/wiki/How-to-use-mongobee#secchangelog) this looks OK. The Spring Data repository and the MongoTemplate are just wrappers around the MongoDB API, so there shouldn't be any issue using them.

Comment: Thank you for replying, so what about my second part of question? 
`So another question is if I use Entity for saving in db, what happens if I change property name in Entity after the changeset applied?`

Comment: Can you ask another question for that? StackOverflow rules are one question each time...